# Can an XML prolog contain custom information?

Tags: xml

Is it legal to add additional custom information somewhere in an XML prolog?  For example, in my case, I would like to add an indicator of which serialiser version was used to create the XML, so that clients receiving the XML could automatically select the correct corresponding de-serialiser.

I could add the information as an attribute of the root tag, but I thought it would be cleaner to add the information in the prolog, like the standard XML version:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
```

something like:

```
<?serialiser version="1.0"?>
```

or is the prolog reserved purely for those things specified by W3C?

Comment: All XML parsers I am aware of would choke on the custom version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add processing instructions such as

`<?serialiser version="1.0"?>`

after the XML declaration, either before or after the DOCTYPE declaration, or at the end of the document. In fact, processing instructions can appear just about anywhere.

Answer (score 2):

From [the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/REC-xml-20081126/#NT-XMLDecl):

```
prolog     ::=       XMLDecl? Misc* (doctypedecl Misc*)?
XMLDecl    ::=      '<?xml' VersionInfo EncodingDecl? SDDecl? S? '?>'
Misc       ::=       Comment | PI | S
PI         ::=      '<?' PITarget (S (Char* - (Char* '?>' Char*)))? '?>'
PITarget   ::=       Name - (('X' | 'x') ('M' | 'm') ('L' | 'l'))
```

So, the `XMLDecl` (optional) portion can't be changed, but the `Misc` part of the  `prolog`, in particular the `PI` (Processing Instruction) can be whatever you wish, including `<?serialiser version="1.0"?>`.

Comment: In the spec under the Misc section it says processing instructions can be added, could this be used to pass such information?

Comment: @DaveJohnston - That appears to be the extension mechanism, though it is **not** part of the prolog.

Comment: Actually, a processing instruction that occurs before the root element IS part of the prolog.

Comment: @Oded, I think you are trying to say that a processing instruction is not part of the XML declaration; that's true.  If the processing instruction occurs before the start-tag of the outermost element, though, it *is* part of the prolog, as the grammar you quote makes clear.  Also, note that the prolog does *not* need to start with `<?xml`, as it does not need to contain any XML declaration at all.